# How to rotate a 3D object, using only local x-, y-, and z-rotations, so that it always faces a camera at the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, rotations

I have been struggling with a difficult problem involving 3D rotations. I first came across this problem in a computer science context, but I've attempted to generalize it a bit before posting.

(I apologize for not posting inline images and only being able to post 2/4 of my images, but I don't have enough reputation.)

Suppose you have a system with a **unit sphere** centered at the origin.

You also have a square "sheet" with marks on it, including a center point.

There is a camera at the origin which can have variable **azimuth**, **pitch**, and **roll** values. An azimuth of 0° corresponds to looking in the -z direction.
Pitch is an up/down change, and roll is a tilt left/right.

From these three values, it is possible to determine a point (x,y,z) on the unit sphere that the camera has centered its view on. (Note that the roll value has no effect on the (x,y,z) position!)

What I would like is for the sheet to be centered at this (x,y,z) point, and also rotated properly so that it always appears in its default view (the top edge is still on top, no perspective foreshortening, etc.) when seen through the camera. Here's an example of what that might look like to an outside observer:

[sheet tangent to unit sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y9jX.png)

The issue is that the sheet has a default orientation - sides parallel to the x- and y-axes, and facing the +z direction. Here's what it looks like in that orientation:

[sheet with default orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKIuG.png)

So, if I place the sheet in 3D space such that its center point is coincident with the unit sphere, the only case when the sheet is tangent (as I want) is when the camera is facing directly along the -z-axis (0 azimuth and 0 pitch). However, this is not enough, because the camera can also change in roll. For example, if the camera is facing along -z (0 azimuth) with 0 pitch, but 30° roll clockwise, then the sheet has to be rotated 30° around the z-axis.

Luckily, I can rotate the sheet around its **local** x, y, and z axes (each axis is parallel to its respective world axis and intersects the sheet's center point).

So the question is, **given the (x,y,z) point on the unit sphere where I want the sheet to be centered, as well as the roll value of the camera, how do I rotate the *default* sheet around its local x-, y-, and z-, axes such that the sheet is tangent with the unit sphere, and properly oriented so that it appears upright with respect to the camera?**

I have tried investigating such topics as spherical coordinates, Euler angles, rotation matrices, etc, but I can't fully understand them and/or they appear incomplete with respect to the constraints on this problem.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your description. (Don't worry, this happens in a majority of people describing similar problems.) Your default sheet has its center at and is tangent to the point $(0,0,1)$ on the unit sphere? The only rotations about the center of this sheet that will leave the sheet tangent are ones that rotate around the $z$ axis and/or flip the $x,y$ plane. This seems relatively boring and unlikely to be what you meant. Can you help clarify?

Comment: And I think what you are describing is that you want the camera's line of sight to be *normal* to the plane of the sheet. Is this correct?  If so, why don't you just consider the camera as pointing at the center of the default sheet, and then using a rotation *around the origin* to move the line of sight of the camera to point through your special point $(x,y,z)$ with the proper roll? The default sheet would be carried along by the transformation to remain oriented to the camera.

Comment: The sheet is not always at (0,0,1); it can be tangent to any point on the globe. You are correct in noting that it is easier to just rotate the sheet about the origin, but that is where the difficulty comes from - you have to simulate a proper rotation of the sheet around the origin such that (a) the sheet is tangent to the sphere and (b) the "T" mark always appears on top relative to the user... and do so only using local rotations of the sheet about the point where the camera's line of sight intersects the sphere (i.e., where the sheet is tangent, i.e., the center point of the sheet).

Comment: If you'd like to know where this comes from, I was programming something using a 3rd party library which only allows you to draw things in this manner, which motivated this question. It wasn't critical functionality (actually just for debugging), and I eventually dropped the feature.

Comment: I'm just saying what you said is misleading because it's not really a "local" rotation of the sheet in the sense that it's a rotation about an origin in the center of the sheet. It's a rotation about the camera, and the sheet is normal to the axis of rotation so that it rotates in a plane. You should *only* use rotations about the camera: I don't see any difficulty.

Comment: ... except for figuring out all the weird conventions around where measurements are measured from. Azimuth is clockwise angle in the $x,y$ plane? Where does zero azimuth point? Along the x-axis or along the y-axis

Comment: I suppose the conventions don't really matter, but 0 azimuth is the -z axis. In terms of the rotation about the center of the SHEET: you're again absolutely right, rotations around the camera are so much easier. *But this problem does not allow you to do that*. (Because the programming library that I was using only offers rotations about a local center, not the camera.) The difficulty lies in only being able to use local rotations, when rotating around the camera would be so much easier.

Comment: Well, conventions absolutely matter if you want to avoid a lot of confusion. What plane does the azmuth travel in after it starts on the z axis? does it pan into the $x,z$ plane or the $y,z$ plane?

Comment: Saying your program can't rotate around the camera is tantamount to it not being able to do 3d rotations at all, as far as I can see.

Comment: Azimuth pans along the xz plane, defining the "horizon". The y axis is for "height", pointing to the zenith.

Comment: As for the program, it's a pretty barebones third party library, which explains the lack of rotation support. However at this point it's not really too relevant anymore - I'd just prefer to think about it abstractly (which is why this wasn't posted on gamedev). This library only supports local rotations of the objects it generates.